# Access __init__ variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was wondering is there a way to access the coords variable from outside the class. Assuming, I cannot change the coords to self.coords.

```
class S_shape(Shape):
    def __init__(self, center):
        coords = [Point(center.x,     center.y),
                  Point(center.x,     center.y + 1),
                  Point(center.x + 1, center.y),
                  Point(center.x - 1, center.y + 1)]
        Shape.__init__(self, coords, 'green')
        self.center_block = self.blocks[0]
        self.shift_rotation_dir = True
        self.rotation_dir = -1
```

I can't seem to be able to do it.

Comment: **No** you can't, variables declared inside a function can't be accessed outside of it. Better define it as a class or instance attribute.

Comment: The problem is the class is not mine, and I cannot edit it, I can just access it.

Comment: Are you sure that the the 'Shape' super class doesn't save coords? Given the name, it seems like coords would be an important part of the instance data.

Comment: But you can look what fields a Shape instance has: `dir(Shape(…))`.

Comment: Tried that, the dir(Shape) doesn't contain it.

Comment: You want to look up the fields of an instance, not of the class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way to really get hold of this could be to have a look what the superclass, `Shape`, does with it. If it stores it as an attribute by itself, you can get hold of it.

Comment: knowin what you're doing, you can always monkey patch Shape to store them for you

Answer (score 1):

One dirty hacky (you're awared) way in your situation is wrap `Shape.__init__` method and work within:

```
class Coords():
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

class Point(Coords):
    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Point ({} {})>'.format(self.x, self.y)

class Shape():
    def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
       pass

class S_shape(Shape):
    def __init__(self, center):
        coords = [Point(center.x,     center.y),
                  Point(center.x,     center.y + 1),
                  Point(center.x + 1, center.y),
                  Point(center.x - 1, center.y + 1)]
        Shape.__init__(self, coords, 'green')
        self.shift_rotation_dir = True
        self.rotation_dir = -1


def coordinates_logger(func):
    def wrapper(self, coords, color): # assume we need exactly first arg to __init__
        print coords          # access to coords, perform some needed action here
        self._coords = coords # for example store them
        return func(self, coords, color)
    wrapper.__name__ = func.__name__
    wrapper.__doc__ = func.__doc__
    wrapper.__dict__.update(func.__dict__)
    return wrapper

# monkey-patch superclass
Shape.__init__ =  coordinates_logger(Shape.__init__)

obj = S_shape(Coords(1,2)) 
# [<Point (1 2)>, <Point (1 3)>, <Point (2 2)>, <Point (0 3)>]
print obj._coords 
# [<Point (1 2)>, <Point (1 3)>, <Point (2 2)>, <Point (0 3)>]
```